# Compiler warns about argument 6 in call to sendto

Tags: c, sockets, udp

```
socklen_t clilen; // declaration

n = sendto(sockfd1, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &clilen);
if(n < 0)
{
    printf("\nERROR writing to socket\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

While compiling my code, it is giving me a warning like.....

```
warning: passing argument 6 of ‘sendto’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
n = sendto(sockfd1, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &clilen);
```

What to do?

Comment: Why are u passing address of clien? When it takes the socklen_t type?

Comment: It's complaining about the 6th argument not being an integer. Typically this is the sizeof your struct sockaddr_storage variable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try

```
n = sendto(sockfd1, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, clilen);
```

I think the last argument type is `socklen_t` and it's not a pointer, so you don't need to pass the the address of the variable; just pass the variable itself it will work and will not give any warning like you are getting now.

Comment: This is correct.   The length of the socklen depends on the protocol, so you have to tell it how many bytes are valid following the address in the pointer from the previous parameter.

Comment: i tried... i wrote.... `(struct sockaddr *)cli_addr`..... but then it is giving me an error...  **error: cannot convert to a pointer type
   n = sendto(sockfd1, buffer,sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *)cli_addr, &clilen)**;....... @xaxxon @Veracious

Comment: @MilanShah that last parameter should be a call to sizeof() for the appropriate sockaddr type for your selected protocol

Comment: `socklen_t clilen;

Comment: just use the line veraciuos posted no need to change cli_addr to non-pointer... but i think in the last argument you can do `sizeof (struct sockaddr)`or `sizeof cli_addr`

Comment: socklen_t clilen;
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    n = sendto(sockfd1, buffer,sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &clilen);
    if(n < 0)
 {
  printf("\nERROR writing to socket\n");
  exit(0);
 }

now this is the code... then also it is giving an warning....@xaxxon

Comment: Why are u bothered about the 5th argument it is showing warning for 6th argument only, just keep the 5th arg as it is , and make change in 6th arg only. U dnt worry abt 5th argument.

Comment: yaa... you are right... it is working now... no warning now... @Veracious

Comment: recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))    is there any problem in this because it is also showing same warning on argument 6.... @Veracious

Comment: gosh... maybe you should actually READ the manpage.... recvfrom WRITES the size into your variable so it needs the address. While sendto GETS this information from you thats why you pass the variable... These are two different functions... manpage is here for example...http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/recvfrom.html

Answer (score 1):

The prototype is

`ssize_t sendto(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags,const struct sockaddr *dest_addr, socklen_t addrlen);`

So the last argument is not a pointer but an integer of type `socklen_t`
So just pass a `(socklen_t) sizeof (struct sockaddr)`and you should be fine. It says its the 6th parameter but you are working on the 5th.